# Twilio call drops unexpectedly after one minute

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I am using Twilio studio for creating a survey, my issue is whenever the flow arrives at a 'Record' or 'Gather' widget, if the recording time exceeds one minute the call ends unexpectedly. I set 'MAX RECORDING LENGTH' to 180. I checked the call logs, for the 'Record' widget there was no warning and for the 'Gather' widget it shows the following warning:

Msg "phone_call model must have positive speechTimeout. Falling back to model numbers_and_commands with speechTimeout auto."

speechModel "phone_call"

ErrorCode "13335"

LogLevel "WARN"

Answer (score 0):

Open a ticket with Twilio support from the Console, [Submit a Ticket](https://www.twilio.com/console/support/tickets/create) with 3 CallSID's less then 48 hours old demonstrating the issue.

You will want to enable [Voice Trace](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038021053-Enable-Voice-Trace-for-Troubleshooting-Twilio-Call-Audio-and-DTMF-Issues) before reproducing the issue for Twilio Support.